# CORS-Error when using django as backend for ionic app

Tags: django, angular, api, ionic-framework, cors

I'm using Django Rest Framework as a backend for my Ionic app.
I set up the API with JWT and with postman everything works fine.
As soon as I try making a API call from my Ionic app I get the following error messages:

**Error 1**
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mywebsite.com/api/movies. (Reason: header ‘password’ is not allowed according to header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight response).

**Error 2**
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.mywebsite.com/api/movies. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

I run my django app on a apache2 webserver.

django-cors-headers is installed,
added to `installed_apps`,
added to the middleware and `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = Ture`

In my Ionic app the request looks like this:

**Service**

```
fetchMovies() {

  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authService.getToken()}`,
      'username': 'USERNAME',
      'password': 'PASSWORD'

    })
  }

    return this.http.get(this.url, httpOptions).pipe(tap(resData => {
      console.log(resData);
    }));
  }
```

I get the token like this:

```
 getToken() {
    return this.http.post('https://www.mywebsite.com/api-token', this.params);
  }
```

And I use the service as follows:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.moviesServcie.fetchMovies().subscribe();
  }
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?
If you need more information feel free to write a comment!
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why is cors false ??

Comment: oh sorry my fault it actually is ture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ionic native plugin here is the link below

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http

Comment: Thanks for the help. Worked fine so far but now I'm getting the following error:

R3InjectorError(DashboardPageModule)[MoviesService -> MoviesService -> MoviesService -> HTTP -> HTTP -> HTTP]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HTTP!